# C# Update chart values

Tags: c#, charts

How do I update values that have already been created?

Like, I have this chart:

[image: chart]

And then I want to update the chart values with other values. I've already tried many things but I don't manage to make it work...

My code:

```
int ratio = (int)PlayerStats.Kills - PlayerStats.Deaths;

string[] seriesArray = { "Kills", "Assists", "Deaths", "MVPS" , "Headshots", "Ratio" };
int[] pointsArray = { PlayerStats.Kills, PlayerStats.Assists, PlayerStats.Deaths, PlayerStats.MVPS, PlayerStats.Headshots, ratio };

this.chart1.Titles.Add("Statistics Chart");

for (int i = 0; i < seriesArray.Length; i++)
{
    Series series = series = this.chart1.Series.Add(seriesArray[i]);

    series.Points.Add(pointsArray[i]);
}

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;

double realRatio = Math.Round((double)PlayerStats.Kills / PlayerStats.Deaths, 2);
double hsRatio = Math.Round((double)PlayerStats.Headshots / PlayerStats.Kills, 2);

label6.Text = PlayerStats.Kills.ToString();
label7.Text = PlayerStats.Assists.ToString();
label8.Text = PlayerStats.Deaths.ToString();
label11.Text = PlayerStats.MVPS.ToString();
label10.Text = String.Format("{0:P2}", hsRatio);
label9.Text = realRatio.ToString();
```

When I try to run the function a second time (to update the values) it gives me a exception: (inside the loop, first line)

**Additional information: There is already a chart element with the name 'Kills' in 'SeriesCollection'.**

I've managed to that that specific function (chart1.Series.Add(...)) only called once on the startup, but then the other function inside the loop gave me exceptions too.

Well, I hope that you understand my english :P

Comment: inside `for` loop, first check if `serie` already exists. `if (chart1.Series.Any(s => s ==seriesArray[i]))` if so, do not add `series[i]` ,get reference to `i` th serie like follow `var series =(chart1.Series.First(s => s ==seriesArray[i]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you clearing out the chart elements before looping through to add them again?  Something like

```
this.chart1.Series.Clear();
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess that only clears the chart titles, not his values. But anyway, tried and it didn't work :(

Comment: Oops I meant to say clear the series, sorry.  this.chart1.Series.Clear();

Comment: Oh god... I don't believe that I didn't found those functions... THANKS. It worked! (if you can edit your answer for more dumb people like me see :) )